# How to improve performance in matlab operation with 3 for loops?

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying to improve the speed of the following code calculation:

```
for i=1:5440
 for j=1:46
  for k= 1:2
    pol(i,j,k)= kr0*exp(0.8*k*0.1)*(abs((I(i)*exp(-0.1*j*2.5))^0.9)+0.0);
   end
  end
end
```

Where `I` is a vector with 5440 values.

Is there any way to avoid the three for loops and increase the speed of this operation?. I can't find a right solution.

Thanks

Comment: if you haven't done it, initializing the 3D array `pol` will help.        `pol=zeros(5440,46,2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
[i,j,k] = ndgrid(1:5440,1:46,1:2);
pol = kr0*exp(0.8*k*0.1) .* ( abs((I(i).*exp(-0.1*j*2.5)).^0.9) + 0.0);
```

Comment: much more readable and faster than original method, but slower than `bsxfun`.

Comment: true, your methods is about 3 times faster than the above on my machine. I get: `0.1181, 0.0151, 0.0382` seconds (corresponding to triple-loop, bsxfun, ndgrid methods): http://pastebin.com/f5PnRf63

Comment: It's understandable since your method needs to populate three large matrices `i`, `j` and `k`, and index all elements of all of them when doing the calculation. However, it is still less error-prone, since `bsxfun` requires separation of dimensions.

Comment: Thanks to all. I have try both solutions and I'll use this one. I find it easier for me, and the calculation speed improvement is enough. These days I'll change all the program and post a report of the total computation time before (more than 30 minutes) and after the changes.

Comment: I've changed almost all the loops and the new computation time is about 200 seconds. I'll try to change all the other loops to further reduce that time.

Answer (score 3):

Use `bsxfun`for vectorization

```
f1 = @(a,b) (abs((a.*exp(-0.1*b*2.5)).^0.9)+0.0);
f2 = @(c,d) kr0*exp(0.8*c*0.1).*d;
pol = bsxfun(f2, permute(1:2, [3 1 2]), bsxfun(f1, I(:), 1:46));
```

Note that since array `1:2` is on third dimension we need `permute` to convert a matrix of size `1x2` to a matrix of size `1x1x2`.

Here is a benchmark for comparision

```
kr0=1;
I=rand(5440,1);
[pol0, pol] = deal(zeros(5440, 46, 2));

tic
for mm = 1:10,
for i=1:5440
 for j=1:46
  for k= 1:2
    pol0(i,j,k)= kr0*exp(0.8*k*0.1)*(abs((I(i)*exp(-0.1*j*2.5))^0.9)+0.0);
   end
  end
end
end
toc

tic
for mm=1:10
f1 = @(a,b) (abs((a.*exp(-0.1*b*2.5)).^0.9)+0.0);
f2 = @(c,d) kr0*exp(0.8*c*0.1).*d;
pol = bsxfun(f2, permute(1:2, [3 1 2]), bsxfun(f1, I(:), 1:46));
end
toc

isequal(pol0,pol)
```

Which returns

```
Elapsed time is 1.665443 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.306089 seconds.

ans =

     1
```

It is more than 5 times faster and the results are equal.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB is column-major, so if you wanted to keep the loops, you should be able to get some speed up by looping your variables in the k, j, i order instead of i, j, k.